# Add metadata (or additional information) to rspec’s standard html output?

Tags: rspec

I’d like to be able to add certain pieces of metadata to rspec’s standard helm output (`rspec spec/* --format html --out report.html`). We can build out our own html reports, but I’d hate to do that since the standard html formatted is already very close to what we need. Thank you!